# What is the correct cast to be used on enums?

Tags: c++, enums, type-conversion

If I remember right a C-Style conversion is nothing more than an ordered set of conversions `static_cast, dynamic_cast, reinterpret_cast, static_cast...`,
consider:

```
enum NUMBERS
{
    NUMBER_ONE,
    NUMBER_TWO
};

void Do( NUMBERS a )
{
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   

    unsigned int a = 1;
    Do( a ); //C2664
    return 0;
}
```

a C-Style conversion would do

```
Do( (NUMBERS)a );
```

What I would like to know is, what is the correct non C-Style conversion to be made, why?

Comment: A "C-style" conversion never does a `dynamic_cast`.  Only zero to two of `const_cast`, `static_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: do you know the exactly order of the conversions? or maybe it is compiler dependent instead of standard

Comment: First that makes sense out of: `const_cast`; `static_cast`; `static_cast` then `const_cast`; `reinterpret_cast`; or `reinterpret_cast` then `const_cast`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way would be:

```
static_cast<NUMBERS>(a)
```

Because:

> 8) Integer, floating-point, or enumeration type can be converted to
>   any enumeration type (the result is unspecified if the value of
>   expression, converted to the enumeration's underlying type, is not one
>   of the target enumeration values)

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

`dynamic_cast` does runtime checks using RTTI, so it only applies to classes with at least one virtual method.

`reinterprest_cast` is designed to tell the compiler to treat a specific piece of memory as some different type, without any actual runtime conversions.

Comment: Oh nice info, didnt know if the conversion had a value the enum doesn't own would lead into UB

Comment: There actually can be runtime conversions with reinterpret_cast. E.g. the mapping function between ints and pointers, if that makes sense for the memory structure of the hardware.

Comment: Also, dynamic_cast does work on classes without virtual members. (whether that's useful or not is another thing)

Comment: @bames53 Don't know about pointer conversions (a source for that claim would be nice) but for classes without virtual members you're just plain wrong: [example](http://ideone.com/moZpX1).

Comment: dynamic casts on non-polymorphic types: http://ideone.com/d3HEra. On pointer conversions see § 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] paragraphs 3 and 4.

Comment: Yes, you can put `dynamic_cast` where no explicit cast is needed at all. It's like saying you can use it to cast `Base*` to `Base*`.

Comment: The second example does require a cast. You can see 5.2.7/5 for details on when the type is not required to be polymorphic. The type must be polymorphic only when that paragraph does not apply.

Answer (score 5):

```
static_cast<NUMBERS>(a)
```

Because the specification for static_cast includes this:

> A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to
>   an enumeration type. The value is unchanged if the original value is
>   within the range of the enumeration values (7.2). Otherwise, the
>   resulting value is unspecified (and might not be in that range). A
>   value of floating-point type can also be converted to an enumeration
>   type. The resulting value is the same as converting the original value
>   to the underlying type of the enumeration (4.9), and subsequently to
>   the enumeration type.

static_cast is for generally taking values of one type and getting that value represented as another type. There are about two pages of specification covering all the details, but if you understand that basic idea, then you'll probably know when you want to use static_cast. E.g., if you want to convert an integral value from one integral type to another or if you want to convert a floating point value to an integral value.

dynamic_cast is for working with dynamic types, which is mostly only useful for polymorphic, user-defined types. E.g., convert Base * to Derived * iff the referenced object actually is a Derived.

reinterpret_cast is typically for taking the representation of a value in one type, and getting the value that has the same representation in another type; i.e., type punning (even though a lot of type punning is actually not legal in C++). E.g., if you want to access an integer's storage as an array of char.

const_cast is for adding and removing cv qualifiers (const and volatile) at any level of a type. E.g., `int const * volatile **i; const_cast<int volatile ** const *>(i);`

Comment: @BrendanLong There's the why.

Answer (score 0):

`static_cast<>` is the way to go:

[Here's why](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c36yw7x9(v=vs.80).aspx)